# Price formula calculation for Doraemon Story of Season

Tags: story-of-seasons

I am recording [a list of sell price](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15R71KAh0Xa24mGTxWIgRnaUIjWPWjWHtRZXBje6GO94/edit?usp=sharing) for items that has quality to aid my gameplay since I wasn't able to find a good price guide.

I noticed that:

1. Everything have a base price at lowest quality (half star) and it will be a round number that ends with at least one zero.
2. Everything that has same base price will have identical price for better quality.

   (Ex: both Carp and Honey Bee have base price of 40, and they have same price for other quality)

| Name | 0.5⭐ | 1⭐ | 1.5⭐ | 2⭐ | 2.5⭐ | 3⭐ | 3.5⭐ | 4⭐ | 4.5⭐ | 5⭐ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Carp | 40 | 46 | 52 | 59 | 67 | 76 | 86 | 98 | 111 | 126 |
| Honey Bee | 40 | 46 | 52 | 59 | 67 | 76 | 86 | 98 | 111 | 126 |

3. As the quality grows, the price of the item would go up exponentially.

Base on this I concluded that there must be a formula to calculate it all given a base price.

Now, the problem is I couldn't figure out the formula for the price even though I think I have a decent amount of data. Since I have Switch Edition and not the Steam one, I can't poke around with game file either.

I was thinking about formula like this:

[image: price = BasePrice + ( ((Quality/0.5)-1)0.15BasePrice )]

But it's just not quite right. I still felt like this is just more or less a high school level math problem and I forgot most of my math class.

How do I find the formula given the data?